# Python Influxdb_client yields syntax error when query uses map function

Tags: influxdb-2, influxdb-python, flux-influxdb

I've encountered the same behavior several times when querying InfluxDB2 from Python (3.8) using the influxdb_client (1.36.1).
For example, the query:

```
        query = f'\
        from(bucket: "my_bucket")\
        |> range(start: -2d, stop: -1d )\
        |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "my_measurement")\
        |> filter(fn: (r) => (r["_field"] == "my_field"))\
        |> map(fn:(r)=>({r with _value: r._value / 3.0}))\
        |> last()\
        '
```

yields:

```
  File "<fstring>", line 1
    (r with _value)
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know the Flux query is correct, as when I type the same query for example in Grafana or in InfluxDB directly, there is no problem. Can anyone reproduce the case ?